# SQLCLR - Are there any alternatives in the newer SQL Server and .net Framework?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a stored procedure that retrieves data by joining multiple tables but there's a .net assembly which has a detailed logic which provides sorting of the records retrieved through the stored proc. Since I need pagination to display the records on UI, I had to first call the proc and get "all" the records from the proc and then call the .net assembly to get sorting of the records and then apply pagination on top of the sorted records in memory which is not the most optimal solution as all the records every time for every single page.

I was contemplating on using SQLCLR to call the .net assembly method through a UDF or SP and call that UDF/SP from my GET proc.

Is this a best solution for this kind of a problem or are there any alternatives?

Versions - SQL Server 2016 and .Net Framework 4.5

**EDIT**:
@Ben Thul - The records returned by the stored procedure are based on the how they are saved in the persistence layer. There are some data points that needs to be analyzed for each item in the result set returned by the stored proc and based on the values of those data points, the records (which might otherwise feature up top) might get a lower priority ranking. This rules engine is written as a .net assembly. And since this is more of a business logic, ideally this is not a good contender of being part of a stored procedure.
So, once I get those records back, this rules engine has to be called to get the priority ranking of each item in the result set and that's what becomes the default sorting criteria when the grid is loaded.

Comment: you may have to explain your issue with examples,currently this question is not clear

Comment: Do you need all of the records from the base stored procedure returned in order to do the sorting? Is the sorting based on anything that can be determined by having individual rows, or is the order based on the rows relative to each other, in which case you do need them all? How large is the result set? If it all fits into memory to be sorted and the issue is mainly that you don't want to repeat this per each "page", can you store the final results in memory/session and page through the collection, never going back to the DB?

Comment: Depending on when the procedure was written, good pagination techniques may not have been available (e.g. fetch/offset). Are you sure that the sorting still needs to be done in that .NET assembly?

Comment: @Ben Thul - Please see the edit in my question above. Thanks!

Comment: @srutzky - I did contemplate on caching the records, but since the items could be added in the list quite frequently, my cache would go stale very soon.
I also thought about caching the priority ranking that I get from the rules engine (see my edit in the question above), but the values of the data points could also change rapidly which could alter the priority ranking of the records. So couldn't do that either..

Comment: @Vinay What I meant by caching was for each particular User / Session. I would suspect that you would not be changing the priorities and/or overall entries while someone is paging through the results, at least not within a short amount of time (a few minutes, perhaps?). So, I was wondering if you could cache each session's results, based on their sessionID, and expire after X minutes.